# How to use Project Reactor's Scheduler with Executor based libraries?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, amazon-dynamodb, project-reactor, aws-sdk-java-2.0

Project Reactor provides a great way to define which thread pool for code to run on, by defining a `Scheduler`. It also provides a bridge to libraries that use `CompletableFuture`'s though `Mono.fromFuture(..)`.

AWS's [async client for DyanmoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html), executes the `CompletableFuture`'s it returns from the API calls on a `java.util.concurrent.Executor`. By default, it creates an `Executor` backed by a thread pool it also creates. The result is that even streams with a defined `Scheduler` like `Mono.fromFuture(..).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` execute on a thread from the pool the library creates instead of one from the `Schedulers.boundedElastic()`. So we're seeing thread names like `sdk-async-response-0-2`, instead of names like `boundedElastic-1`.

Fortunately, the library allows us to provide our own `Executor` as [shown here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/basics-async.html#advanced-operations), so my question is:

> How do you build an `Executor` that uses a thread from the `Scheduler` *defined on that part of the stream* at runtime?

*Use Case*

We have a repository class, that has a `findById` method and we need the caller to be able to control which `Scheduler` to run on, because it's used in these distinctly different contexts:

1. API responses that are run on the `Schedulers.boundedElastic()` scheduler.
2. Handling Kafka messages that are executed in order, on a thread per partition, from a defined scheduler as shown in the [Reactor Kafka docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/#concurrent-ordered).

*Attempts*

We've tried defining an `Executor` using both `Schedulers.immediate()` and `Runnable::run` as shown here, but both result in executing on the Netty event loop thread (example name: `aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-2`), not a thread from the defined `Scheduler`.

```
DynamoDbAsyncClient.builder()
    .asyncConfiguration(builder -> builder.advancedOption(
        SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption.FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR,
        runnable -> Schedulers.immediate().schedule(runnable)
    ))
    .build();
```

```
DynamoDbAsyncClient.builder()
    .asyncConfiguration(builder -> builder.advancedOption(
        SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption.FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR,
        Runnable::run
    ))
    .build();
```

Comment: Why do you try to use immediate scheduler? That doesn't switch threads. Try to use other schedulers like parallel or elastic.

Comment: I tried the immediate scheduler precisely because I didn't want it to switch threads from what was defined in the stream. Regarding the suggestion to use the parallel or elastic scheduler, leveraging one of those in the Executor would cause it to always be used and ignore the Scheduler that was set on the stream. In our use case, we need it to run on different threads based on what's defined in that stream.

Comment: So you want to switch the event loop threads if I understand it correctly. That's not possible with this mechanism. I doubt it is possible at all. You might have a better chance to get an answer if you open an issue in the GitHub repo of the project.

Comment: No I don't want to switch the event loop threads, nor do I want to run application logic on them. I want the DynamoDB logic run on the threads defined as part of the _active_ scheduler at runtime. So if the active thread is one from an elastic thread pool, or a single thread defined for that part of the stream, I want the DynamoDB logic to be executed on it.

Answer (score 33):

## Part 1. Observe vs. Subscribe

Looking into the question, I see the need to ***observe*** elements after execution on a particular thread. 
To be precise, ***observe*** in this context means *being able to work on a value in the stream on some specific thread. In RxJava, we have a proper operator called precisely like that, but in Project Reactor, we call identical operation as `publishOn`.

Thus, 
*** if you want to process data *** on `Schedulers.boundedElastic()` then you should use the following construction

```
Mono.fromFuture(..)
    .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
```

### BUT Wait, `.subscribeOn` worked as well???

Reading the previous construction, you may start worrying because you are 100% sure that

```
Mono.fromRunnable(..)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
```

Sends `onNext` on the thread `boundedElastic-1`, so what is wrong with the same `fromFuture`.

and here comes a trick:

### Never use `subscribeOn` with `Futures` / `CompletableFuture` or anything which can use own async mechanism underneath

If we look at what is going on behind `subscribeOn`, you will find out something like the following:

```
//  Simplified version of SubscribeOn operator
@Override
public void subscribe(CoreSubscriber<? super T> actual) {
    Scheduler scheduler;
    Publisher<T> parent;
    scheduler.schedule(() -> parent.subscribe(actual));
}
```

Which basically means parent's `subscribe` method will be called on a separate thread.

Such a technique works for `fromRunnable`, `fromSupplier`, `fromCallable` because their logic happens in the `subscribe` method:

```
@Override
public void subscribe(CoreSubscriber<? super T> actual) {
    Operators.MonoSubscriber<T, T>
    sds = new Operators.MonoSubscriber<>(actual);

    actual.onSubscribe(sds);
    // skiped some parts 
    T t = supplier.get();
    if (t == null) {
        sds.onComplete();
    }
    else {
        sds.complete(t);
    }
}
```

which means it is almost equal to

```
scheduler.schedule(() -> {
    T t = supplier.get();
    if (t == null) {
        sds.onComplete();
    }
    else {
        sds.complete(t);
    }
})
```

In contrast, `fromFuture` works much trickier. 
A short quiz.

**On which thread we may observe a value? (assume execution happens on thread Main, and the task is executing on ForkJoinPool)**

```
var future = CompletableFuture
.supplyAsync(() -> {
  return value;
})
... // some code here, does not metter just code

future.thenAccept(value -> {
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread())
});
```

And the correct answer....

It may be Thread Main 
or it may be Thread from ForkJoinPool 
... 
because it is racy... and at the point, we consume value, the value may be already delivered, so we just read `volatile` field on the reader thread (thread Main), otherwise, thread Main just going to set an `acceptor` so the acceptor will be invoked later on the `ForkJoinPool` thread.

Right, that is why when you use `fromFuture` with `subscribeOn`, there is no guarantee that the `subscribeOn` thread will observe the value of the given `CompletableFuture`.

That is why `publishOn` is the only way to ensure value processing is happening on the desired Thread.

### Alright, should I use `publishOn` all the way down???

And yes and no. It depends.

If you use `Mono` - in 99% of the cases, you may use `publishOn` if you want to make sure that your data processing is happening on a particular thread - always use `publishOn`.

**Do not worry about a potential overhead**, Project Reactor takes care of you even if you used it accidentally. Project Reactor has several optimization which may replace your `publishOn` with `subscribeOn` (if it is safe without breaking the behavior) at runtime so you will get the best.

## Part 2. Falling down the rabbit hole of `Scheduelr`s

### Never ever use `Schedulers.immediate()`

it is almost no-ops scheduler which basically does

```
Schedulers.immediate().scheduler(runnable) {
   runnable.run()
}
```

Right, it does nothing useful for reactor users, and we use it only for internal needs.

### Alright, so how then I can use Scheduler to use it in an imperative world as executor

There are two options:

#### Fast path: Step by Step guide

1.a) Create your bounded `Executor`. (e.g. `Executors.fixed...`) 
1.b) Create your bounded `ScheduledExecutorService` if you want to get the power of periodic task and delayed tasks 
2) Create a `Scheduler` from your executor using `Schedulers.fromExecutorXXX` API 
3) Use your bounded `Executor` in the imperative world, use your `Scheduler` which is a wrapper around the bounded one for the reactive world

#### Long path

Coming soon...

## Part 3. How to serialize executions.

Coming soon

Comment: hey @Oleh, great answer! super non-obvious stuff for a beginner to be honest, this should be made more clear somewhere in the docs